# Sharepoint 2010 Filtering a List Based on The Current User

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

I am pretty new at SharePoint. We are using SharePoint 2010. I need some help on some filtering. We have a library that we want to filter based on the current user and restrict everyone else. In one of the columns in the list is Department. I want only Joe to see items assigned to HR department. I want only Sally to see items assigned to Accounting department, etc. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have only few rows in the list, this can be done without programming

1) Create a new [presence/people] type column Ex name: ViewBy

2) In the ViewBy column add Joe to all rows with column department as HR/sally to Accounting

3) Create filter. Go to Library Settings-> Views Section-> All Documents, then scroll down to filters and show items only when column  ViewBy is equal to [Me]

Comment: I like this idea. Help me a little further though. I created my column ViewBy. How do I write text in that field when looking at my library of forms that have already been filled out.

Also, is there a way to autopopulate that field? We would need like an if statement... If dempartment = HR, then fill in ViewBy to Sally. Thanks for your help!